# Reflection across the plane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be the linear transformation given by reflecting across the plane $S=\{x:-x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}$ (...)

Then, $S={\rm gen}[(1,1,0),(1,0,1)].$

But how can I get the matrix $R_v$ such that reflects across $S$?

Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers you've received?

Comment: @GerryMyerson He asked the same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693391/).

Answer (score 5):

The vector $\vec{n}=\langle -1,1,1 \rangle$ is normal to the plane, thus $T$ maps $\vec{n}$ to $-\vec{n}=\langle 1,-1,-1 \rangle$. It also fixes the vectors $\vec{u}= \langle 1,1, 0 \rangle$ and $\vec{v} = \langle -1,1,-2 \rangle$ that are perpendicular to each other and to $\vec{n}$.  More generaly, $\vec{u}$ could be any vector whose dot product with $\vec{n}$ is zero (such vectors are easy to find) and $\vec{v} = \vec{n}\times\vec{u}$.

In the basis determined by $\vec{n}$, $\vec{u}$, and $\vec{v}$, your matrix looks like
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1  & 0 \\
  0 & 0 &  1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

The matrix $A$ whose columns are formed by $\vec{n}$, $\vec{u}$, and $\vec{v}$ form a similarity transformation that changes the diagonal matrix $E$ formed by the eigenvalues $-1$, $1$, and $1$ into the matrix you want.  Thus, your matrix is

$$A \cdot E \cdot A^{-1} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1  & 0 \\
  0 & 0 &  1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot
\frac{1}{6}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -2 & 2 & 2 \\
 3 & 3 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\frac{1}{3}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 2 & 1 & -2 \\
 2 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

Of course, it's easy to check that this matrix behaves as advertised by multiplying it by the vectors above.

**Addendum**

This technique can be used to derive Bubba's answer, although I used Mathematica to do the heavy lifting for me.

```
A = Transpose[{{a, b, c}, {0, -c, b}, {b^2 + c^2, -a*b, -a*c}}];
FullSimplify[A.{{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}.Inverse[A]] /.
  a^2 + b^2 + c^2 -> 1 // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1-2 a^2 & -2 a b & -2 a c \\
 -2 a b & 1-2 b^2 & -2 b c \\
 -2 a c & -2 b c & 2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

*However*, seeing Bubba's answer reminded me wonderful and simple Householder reflections are. Just define the function $f:{\mathbb R}^n \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^n$ by $f(x)=\vec{x}-2\vec{n}(\vec{n}^T\vec{x})$, where $\vec{x}$ is a column vector and $\vec{n}$ is a unit column vector denoting your normal.  It's super simple to check that $f$ maps $\vec{n}$ to $-\vec{n}$:
$$f(\vec{n}) = \vec{n}-2\vec{n}(\vec{n}^T\vec{n}) = \vec{n}-2\vec{n}1=-\vec{n},$$
where $\vec{n}^T\vec{n}=1$, since $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector.  It's also super simple to see that any vector $\vec{x}$ perpendicular to $\vec{n}$ is fixed by $f$, since
$$f(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}-2\vec{n}(\vec{n}^T\vec{x}) = \vec{x}-2\vec{n}0=\vec{x}.$$

Factoring out the $\vec{x}$ from the definition of $f$, we see the matrix you need:
$$I-2\vec{n}\,\vec{n}^T.$$

Applying this to your situation, we get the same matrix as above.
\begin{align}
I-\vec{n}\,\vec{n}^T &=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
-
2\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 1 &
   1 \\
\end{array}
\right)/\sqrt{3}\\
&= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
- 2\frac{1}{3}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & -1 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\frac{1}{3}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 2 & 1 & -2 \\
 2 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Note: the sqrt(3) is from the magnitude of the normal vector.

Answer (score 4):

The matrix that reflects across the plane through the origin with *unit* normal $\mathbf{N} = (a,b,c)$ is:
$$
\mathbf{I} - 2\mathbf{N}^T\mathbf{N} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
{1- 2a^2} &   {-2ab}  &   {-2ac} \\
 {-2ab}   &  {1-2b^2} &   {-2bc} \\
 {-2ac}   &   {-2bc}  &  {1-2c^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Reflection_2) for reference. A normal of your plane is $\mathbf{N} = (-1,1,1)$, so plug in $a=-1/\sqrt{3}$, $b=1\sqrt{3}$, $c=1\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: It's important that the normal $\bf N$ be a *unit* vector. I went ahead and made the minor edit.

Comment: I also updated my answer to reflect the relationship between the answers.

Comment: @Mark -- you are correct, of course. Thanks for the fix. I also added the bit about $N^T N$

Comment: I think that this is for a plane which includes the origin ( [0 0 0 ] is in the plane).  A nice derivation of this formula for an _arbitrary_ plane - a plane not including the origin - is given in [Rotation about an arbitrary axis and reflection through an arbitrary plane](http://ami.ektf.hu/uploads/papers/finalpdf/AMI_40_from175to186.pdf) by Emőd Kovács

Comment: Algorithm for reflection in an arbitrary plane is given in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/43692/116523

Comment: @WillC -- My answer says that it applies to a plane through the origin. And the OP's question is about a plane through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

$R$ is the matrix whose columns are the results of reflecting $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ across $S$. So, can you work out the result of reflecting each of those three vectors across $S$?